# How can I add headers into the top of the page?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to add headers in my Expression Engine site, but not getting exactly how can I. I've format of headers in php

```
{exp:http_header Feature-Policy="sync-xhr \'self\' https://example.com"}
{exp:http_header x_content_type_options="nosniff"}
```

Here is my header in php:

```
<?php

header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=454556000; includeSubDomains');

header('Content-Security-Policy: default-src \'self\'');

header('Feature-Policy: sync-xhr \'self\' https://example.com');

header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');

header('X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block');

header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

header('Referrer-Policy: strict-origin');

?>
```

I want to add like the above sample I attached.

```
{exp:http_header Feature-Policy="sync-xhr \'self\' https://example.com"}
{exp:http_header x_content_type_options="nosniff"}
```

How can I add this:
header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=454556000; includeSubDomains');

in expressionengine?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you activate the "HTTP Header" Plugin?

Comment: Is that default plugin? How can I activate?

Comment: Or I need to install that plugin first?

Comment: Or can I add this without plugin? I think this exp:http_header suppose to be work with plugin, so can I add without plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes "HTTP Header" is the default plugin of the EE.
This plugin must be installed if you want to use HTTP header tag.
Add `$config['allow_php'] = 'y';` to enable the php.
Enable php for the specific template.